# SQL Case statement, which is most effective/quickest?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I'm trying to write a CASE statement in a VIEW and I am wondering which is the best/preferred way of doing it. I'm investigating a FIELD VALUE and want to assign a different value to it, depending on the Value of FIELD1, an example:

```
CASE WHEN Field1 = 'X' THEN 1
WHEN Field1 = 'Y' THEN 0
WHEN Field1 = 'Z' THEN 2
ELSE 4
END
```

or

```
CASE Field1
WHEN 'X' THEN 1
WHEN 'Y' THEN 0
WHEN 'Z' THEN 2
ELSE 4
END
```

Any help which is more proper?

This is running against a lot of data, i want this to be as quick as possible.

Comment: Those case expressions are not equivalent, field2 are in only one of them.

Comment: @jarlh how so are they different? Yah i just fixed that, my bad

Comment: They are same, choose one to your liking.

Comment: you need to see the query plan. Check it and you will know.

Comment: I'd go with alternative 2, since it's easier to write (_without errors..._), to read and to maintain.

Comment: A `case` _expression_ in the select list doesn't really matter performance-wise. But you shouldn't have them in ON or WHERE clause, because they are difficult to optimize.

Comment: @jarlh The second version becomes attractive for a long equality `CASE` expression.  In that case (no pun intended), it frees us from having to write `CASE WHEN` multiple times ad nauseam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `CASE` expressions should generate the same execution plan/behavior.  However, both do not offer the same flexibility in syntax.  Your second version only allows you to do equality comparisons of `Field1` to other literal values:

```
CASE Field1 WHEN 'X' THEN 1
            WHEN 'Y' THEN 0
            WHEN 'Z' THEN 2
            ELSE 4
END
```

However, the first style is more flexible, and lets you use any logical comparison involving `Field1`.  For example, you could try:

```
CASE WHEN Field1 BETWEEN 1 AND 10 THEN 0
     WHEN Field1 > 10 THEN 1
     ELSE 2 END
```

Comment: I would be surprised if there were, and even if so, it is doubtful that this would be anything near to your biggest optimization problem.